# How to access the parent props from the child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

How to access Parent's props in the Child's tag and function sayhello?
(I can access siblings and children without passing props as an argument but not the parent)
____________________________________________

And (away from this example) 
 If `this` refers to `Parent`, how to access Child's props?

And if `this` refers to Child as an html tag, is there a function to convert the result into the react component class? (not reassigning this as the class to a new variable `() =>` instead of `function()`)
Child:

```
class Child extends Parent{
   constructor(props){
       super(props);
   }
   render() {
       return (
          <p>{Parent.props.hello}</p>     // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
          <button onClick={sayhello.bind(this)}></button> // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
       ); 
   }
}
```

Parent:

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
       super(props);
   }
   render() {
      <>
          <Child/>
      </>
   }
}
```

sayhello:

```
function sayhello(){
   console.log(Parent.props);     // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing `class Child extends Parent `? Didn't you mean `class Child extends React.Component`? "Parent-Child" relation is defined when you render `<Child/>` in the render of `Parent` component. Isn't it?

Comment: When I print ```this``` of ```class Child extends Parent``` I find Parent and Parent's props names come up many times in the console; as for  ```class Child extends React.Component```, the names don't come up as if no relations or relevance.

Comment: You need to pass props to children component. <Child parentProps={this.props}/>

Comment: Have you read the related section in docs? https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: As @aleksa_95 suggested; that is how you pass props from one component to the other. You can pass *data* as well as *function* props in the same manner.

Comment: @Dennis yes, I had

Answer (score 0):

If you `bind` the function in component, you can refer to `this.props`:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={sayhello.bind(this)}>Click</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Child someProp="hello" />
      </>
    );
  }
}

function sayhello() {
  console.log(this.props);
}
```

[image: Edit React Template (forked)]